# Writing to a text file with a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How to set up three textfields on a HTML page and store the data input in a text file on the server by using an Servlet?

Comment: What have you [tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: do you have the simple java file which can write in to a text file ???

Comment: I've tried a lot of different things with an applet, and found out a Servlet could be the way. I have a lot of different examples where I write to a txt file in an applet, but when I sign the applet and put it up on the website it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a form in the HTML page and have the action set to the name of the Servlet.
2. Within that Servlet, call the parameters with request.getParameter("...");
3. Append the combined String to the file using something like:

   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FileName", true)));
   out.println(createFullNameString(firstName, middleName, lastName));
   out.close();

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
 <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
 <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />

    in servlet

    String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
String middlename=request.getParameter("middlename");
String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
```